# What is the purpose of MCP/FCU and FMS selecte altitude?

Tags: radar, mode-s

in Radar Mode S Asterix message, the  Mode S Enhanced Surveillance (EHS) provides

- FMS Selected Altitude.
- MCP/FCU Selected Altitude.

What is their purpose?

What is the differnte between FMS and MCP/FCU ?

Answer (score 2):

Both are altitude inputs for the autopilot of the aircraft.

The FMS Selected Altitude is the Altitude selected by the Flight Management System (FMS). The FMS hold the flight plan as well as Standard Instrument Ddeparture (SID) and Standard Arrival Routes (STAR) procedures. These can be used to provide a Selected Altitude directly to the autopilot when the FMS manages the vertical profile of the aircraft (VNAV mode).

Another way to provide the autopilot with a refence altitude is to put it manually into the Mode Control Panel (Boeing parlance) / Flight Control Unit (Airbus parlance).

On some aircraft, the FMS can manage the vertical path in VNAV but the pilot can put an Altitude Intervention through the MCP.

In addition to the altitude fields, also the autopilot status and the current target altitude source is trasmitted in Mode-S.

The purpose of having these fields is that it allows the Air Traffic Control System to do checks (automated or manual by an air traffic controller), confirming that a descent/climb has started to the cleared altitude, that a level off is going to happen at a certain altitude etc.